# React JSX vs function call to present component

Tags: reactjs, jsx

```
const Component = ({ text }) => (
  <div>{text}</div>
)

const Example = () => (
  <div>
    <Component text="123" />
    {Component({ text: "123" })}
  </div>
)
```

Is there any difference between the two methods of rendering? Which is preferred and why?

Comment: Both will end up as `React.createElement("div", null, text );` calls :) I would use the JSX notation, as it makes it obvious that a Component will be rendered.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I recommend that you don't call function components but render them instead. This approach may lead to unexpected behaviors (mainly if you are using hooks). For more details see [Don't call a React function component](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/dont-call-a-react-function-component) by Kent C. Dodds.

However the second is faster because it's not mounted with `React.createElement`. See this [great article by Philippe Lehoux](https://medium.com/missive-app/45-faster-react-functional-components-now-3509a668e69f) that talks about the differences (mainly in performance) between both approaches.

Comment: in the second case, react would not handle the lifecycle of the component as much as I understand

Comment: https://kentcdodds.com/blog/dont-call-a-react-function-component

Comment: As @gaurav5430 pointed out with Kent's article, calling react components can lead to unexpected behaviors. Edited my answer to make it clear.