# React JSX vs function there are difference in focus handling?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, focus

In [React JSX vs function call to present component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47288322/react-jsx-vs-function-call-to-present-component)
the question was answered with 'no' when it comes to a difference between function call or (tag) component.

Here I have a confusing example where the difference between function call and tag is leading to a change in focus behaviour. I am sure there are React experts out there with a reasonable explanation - unfortunately I am not yet there ;-)

Here the code with the commented differences between tag and function call:

```js
import React, {useState} from 'react';

function FocusRiddle() {

    const [currentRow, setCurrentRow] = useState({firstName: 'Barack', lastName: 'Obama'});

    // This keeps the focus correctly
    return <div>{Att()}</div>;

    // This loses the focus after every letter !!!
    // return <div><Att /></div>;

    function Att() {
        return <div>
            <h1>Welcome to Focus Riddle</h1>
            <div>
                <MyInput key={'firstName'} name={'firstName'} row={currentRow} action={updateRow}/>
            </div>
            <div>
                <MyInput key={'lastName'} name={'lastName'} row={currentRow} action={updateRow}/>
            </div>
            <div>
                <button onClick={() => alert(JSON.stringify(currentRow))}>Show Row</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    }


    function updateRow(name, value) {
        setCurrentRow({...currentRow, [name]: value});
    }

}

function MyInput({name, row, action}) {
    return <input
        value={row[name]}
        onChange={(event) => action(name, event.target.value)}/>
}

export default FocusRiddle;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `Att()` is equivalent to implementing a normal component, as you just declared a function and called it in components scope.

So nothing special here, the state should persist:

```
function FocusRiddle() {
  const [currentRow, setCurrentRow] = useState({
    firstName: "Barack",
    lastName: "Obama",
  });

  function updateRow(name, value) {
    setCurrentRow({ ...currentRow, [name]: value });
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <h1>Welcome to Focus Riddle</h1>
        <div>
          <MyInput
            key={"firstName"}
            name={"firstName"}
            row={currentRow}
            action={updateRow}
          />
        </div>
        <div>
          <MyInput
            key={"lastName"}
            name={"lastName"}
            row={currentRow}
            action={updateRow}
          />
        </div>
        <div>
          <button onClick={() => alert(JSON.stringify(currentRow))}>
            Show Row
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

But, on calling `<Att/>` you create [React Element](https://reactjs.org/docs/rendering-elements.html), because using JSX syntax is a sugar syntax for [`React.createElement`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#createelement). See [JSX in depth](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html).

So with it, React elements's aware of props change and render when their **parent is rendered**.

When you typing in `input` and calling `setCurrentRow`, `FocusRiddle` gets rendered, and `Att` component **unmounts** (because you re-declare `Att` component on every render) therefore you lose focus.